# Unrecognized selector error trying to use a tap gesture recognizer

Tags: ios, swift, uitapgesturerecognizer, unrecognized-selector

I am trying to create a sign up page for my app. But I am getting an error when I run the app.

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFBoolean select:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10ad5a690'

What is wrong with my code and what it mean?

Here is the my code:

```
import UIKit

class SignupViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var profileImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var usernameTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var emailTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var passwordTextField: UITextField!

    let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
    var selectedPhoto: UIImage!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: true, action: #selector(SignupViewController.select(_:)))
           tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        profileImage.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }

    func selectPhoto(tap:UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        self.imagePicker.delegate = self
        self.imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.camera) {
            self.imagePicker.sourceType = .camera
        }else{
            self.imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        }
        self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    @IBAction func CancelDidTapped(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil) 
    }

    @IBAction func RegisterDidTapped(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    }
}

extension SignupViewController: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate{

    //ImagePicker

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
        selectedPhoto = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as? UIImage
        self.profileImage.image = selectedPhoto
        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error indicates that you're incorrectly calling your `select(_:)` function on a `boolean`:

```
 '-[__NSCFBoolean select:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10ad5a690'
```

After examining your code to see where and how you've called `select(_:)`, it becomes clear that the problem is that you're setting your `UITapGestureRecognizer`'s target to a boolean, i.e. `true`:

```
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: true, action: #selector(SignupViewController.select(_:)))
```

when it should be set to your function's view controller. For example, in this case, you probably want to set your target to `self`:

```
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(SignupViewController.select(_:)))
```

As for the `select(_:)` method you're calling, it seems to me that you made a typo and that you meant to call the `selectPhoto(tap:)` method you've created instead; in which case, your tap gesture declaration and initialization should instead be:

```
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, 
                           action: #selector(SignupViewController.selectPhoto(tap:)))
```

Comment: But when i write selectPhoto so i get error, ( Type SignupViewController has no member "selectPhoto") . I am using Xcode 8 and Swift 3

Comment: Ok, i fixed that just to write "tap" instead of  "_" .

Comment: Thanks for your comment.